# Visual studio code single quotes bug

Tags: visual-studio-code

i just would like to ask about the visual studio code for mac os.
I have no idea what happend with this app, i have reinstalled it already.

Everytime when i'm trying to write double single quotes ('') it writes three of them (''') and it's driving me crazy, i tried to change keyboard language, settings in visual studio code, nothing fixing this issue.

Has anyone has issue like i'm describing above?
Thank You.

Comment: which language file are you working with? Also do you have any extensions?

Comment: i deleted all extensions, it's problematic on js or php, i have to press  '  + spacebar to get 'this', not sure if it has something with my language where we use the ' symbol  as a strech symbol for letters, for example we don't write "woooou", we do "wóu" instead.

Comment: I tested it also with usa keyboard layout, and now the double quotes "  " need to  have pressed spacebar to get "code", or i will get """ tribble double quotes.